# converting grid references to long/lat

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, georeferencing, latitude-longitude, geolocation

If I import from a POST DB a set of points that are referenced by grid reference, will the long/lat decimal also be added to the file? or will I have to convert the points to long/lat myself?

In short: I am importing grid references, but want to display long/lat + store the long/lat?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Import where? Please tell what software are you using. Is POST DB, a postgis database?

Comment: Hi, I am storing into postgis db sorry@AlexandreNeto

Comment: The software are you "importing" your points to would also be helpfull.

Comment: I found the solution using the_geom column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is already in the desired Geographic Coordinate Reference System (CRS), if your table does not have any Latitute and Longitude columns, you can always calculate them still in Postgis, using [st_x](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [st_y](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Y.html) functions, before "importing" it elsewhere. The SQL code will be something like this:

```sql
SELECT *, st_y(the_geom) as latitude, st_x(the_geom) as longitude
FROM your_table
```